# jquery form.submit() triggers handlers, but not the actual submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form with a submit button and handler. The handler does some validation and does preventDefault() if validation is not cool.

I have a second button on my form to submit without validation. My logic of thinking is: This button will add a class indicating, not to validate, and then trigger the submit. The submit event will always check if it should validate or not.

Some code:

```
    //Add handler for no-validation submit
    $('#button-no-falco').click(function() {
        $('#form').addClass('no-falco');
        $('#form').submit();
    });


    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        //If form has no-falco, don't validate.
        if ($(this).hasClass('no-falco')) {
            console.log("Skipping validation. Just submit.");
            return;
        }

        //Validation code

        e.preventDefault();


    });
```

Some HTML:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{action_url}}" name="edit-object">
    <!-- bunch of inputs -->
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save!</button>
    <button type="button" id="button-no-falco" class="btn btn-default">No validation</button>
</form>
```

So now clicking the button-no-falco button will cause the whole validation to be skipped, there's even the log message showing up. However the actual form is not being submitted.

if I click the regular submit button (after having clicked the other button) the form does submit.

What's going on?

Comment: I think u need to add return true ; here  if ($(this).hasClass('no-falco')) {console.log("Skipping validation. Just submit.");   return true; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the button id from submit to something else

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save!</button>
<button type="button" id="button-no-falco" class="btn btn-default">No validation</button>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/978JS/), [with id submit](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/978JS/2/)

It overrides the form method `submit` causing the `.submit()` call to fail

Comment: I would not have guessed that in a million years. Changed the ID to 'submit-button' and suddenly it works.

Comment: Yeah! Having `name=submit` or `id=submit` causes the jQuery handler to fail! Can someone please explain the technical mess behind this? Because to my plain eye, it makes no sense at all... o.O

Comment: @RomeoSierra `It overrides the form method submit causing the .submit() call to fail`, Form' has a submit property which is a function, but when you have an input element with name `submit`, the form's `submit` property value will be overriden to the element(with name submit` reference

Comment: So in brief, what it means is **behavior of the form attribute is kinda dependent on the `name` attribute** isn't it?

Comment: @RomeoSierra Yes, it is a feature which allows you to fetch the input values using the form reference. Ex: If you have a input with name age and a form reference `frm` then you can use `frm.age.value` to fetch the value of the `age` field

Comment: Starting to make a little sense now. Thank you @ArunPJohny. (y)

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding:

```
var form=$('form');
```

Comment: Oh, right, sloppy me. I do this, but that code I didn't post. I'll edit it in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('.btn-default').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('id') == 'button-no-falco') {
    $('#form').submit();
  } else {
   // add code for validation and if validation returns true then submit form
  }

});
```

and remove this,

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
        //If form has no-falco, don't validate.
        if ($(this).hasClass('no-falco')) {
            console.log("Skipping validation. Just submit.");
            return;
        }

        //Validation code

        e.preventDefault();


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the binding then submit, no need to add and check for a class

```
$('#button-no-falco').click(function() {
    form.off(); //remove all registered handlers
    form.submit();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/978JS/4/

Comment: I like this one too! Hadn't thought of that!